# Testing with Jest FakeTimers

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, usefaketimers

I'm having a problem testing a particular component.  It is a wrapper that includes a progress bar which in turn receives a `now` number prop (0-100 percentage) which dictates the position of the bar.
In the test, I've recruited Jest's fakeTimers to confirm that the correct prop is being sent to the `ProgressBar` component.

This is the implementation of the wrapper:

```js
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {ProgressBar} from 'local-repo';

export type Props = {
  period: number;
};

const INCREMENT = 1000;

const Wrapper = ({period}: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const [progressPercentage, setProgressPercentage] = useState(0);
  const timerRef = useRef<NodeJS.Timer>();

useEffect(() => {
    timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      const getProgressPercentage = (previousState: number) =>
        (((previousState / 100) * period + INCREMENT) * 100) / period;
      setProgressPercentage((previousState) => getProgressPercentage(previousState));
    }, INCREMENT);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (progressPercentage >= 100) clearInterval(timerRef.current);
  }, [progressPercentage]);

  return (
      <ProgressBar now={progressPercentage} />
  );
};

export default Wrapper;
```

This is the test:

```js
import {render, screen, cleanup} from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import {ProgressBar} from 'local-repo';
import Wrapper, {
  type Props,
} from './Wrapper';

jest.mock('local-repo');
(ProgressBar as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(({}) => <div>ProgressBar</div> );

jest.spyOn(global, 'setInterval');

const INCREMENT = 1000;
const getRenderResult = (props: CreditLimitIncreaseProcessingProps) =>
  render(<Wrapper {...props} />);

const mockProps = { period: 20000, };

describe('Wrapper Tests', () => {
  let asFragment;
  let getByText;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const _ = {asFragment, getByText} = getRenderResult(mockProps);
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
      jest.useRealTimers();
      jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('should match the screenshot', () => {
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('should render the ProgressBar', () => {
    getByText('ProgressBar');
  });

  it('should update the ProgressBar correctly', () => {
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(INCREMENT * 5)
    expect(ProgressBar).toHaveBeenCalledWith({now: 25});
  });
});
```

The basic idea is that after `INCREMENT * 5` interval, the `now` prop calculates out to 25(%) considering that the `period` is 20 times the INCREMENT.  In simpler terms, 5 seconds is 25 % of 20 seconds.

The Wrapper works as expected.  But the tests fail, complaining that, though it expects `25`, it receives a value of `0`.

What am I missing?

Comment: I had a similar issue with `setTimeout` until I realized that between component rerender, I cleared and created a new `setTimeout` instance. So to mock ALL featured timeouts I do `while (jest.getTimerCount()) { act(() => jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()); } }`